# Fetch API cannot load localhost:3000/send. URL scheme "localhost" is not supported

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, fetch-api

I am using Node Js as backend and basic html css js for frontend. I am sending request through node js that

```
app.get("/send", async (req, res) => {
  let products = await Product.find();
  products = await products;
  res.send(products);
});
```

and getting fetch on an html page:

```
const getData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("localhost:3000/send", {
      method: "GET",
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  };
  getData();
```

But i am not getting the data, I have tested the api on Postman it works fine there. But throwing error on browser:

Error is :

Fetch API cannot load localhost:3000/send. URL scheme "localhost" is not supported.

Please help me out. Bundles of thanks!

Comment: Add `http://` or `https://`

Answer (score 3):

You should specify localhost as being `http://localhost` or `https://localhost` - otherwise `fetch` can't be sure which protocol you are mentioning:

```
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/send", { ... });
```

Comment: The http would be redirected to https. Why?